# Java get Substring value from String

Tags: java, string, split, substring

I have string

```
 String path =    /mnt/sdcard/Album/album3_137213136.jpg
```

I want to only strings `album3`.
How can I get that substring.

I am using `substring through index.` 
Is there any other way because album number is getting changed because it will fail in like `album9, album10`.

Comment: How about `Regular expressions` ?

Comment: @kocko yeah.. Good one bro!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obligatory regex solution using [`String.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
String album = path.replaceAll(".*(album\\d+)_.*", "$1");
```

Use of it:

```
String path = "/mnt/sdcard/Album/album3_137213136.jpg";
String album = path.replaceAll(".*(album\\d+)_.*", "$1");
System.out.println(album); // prints "album3"
path = "/mnt/sdcard/Album/album21_137213136.jpg";
album = path.replaceAll(".*(album\\d+)_.*", "$1");
System.out.println(album); // prints "album21"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a regular expression, but it seems like using `index` is the simplest in this case:

```
int start = path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
int end = path.lastIndexOf('_');
String album = path.substring(start, end);
```

You might want to throw in some error checking in case the formatting assumptions are violated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String path =   "/mnt/sdcard/Album/album3_137213136.jpg";
    String[] subString=path.split("/");
    for(String i:subString){
          if(i.contains("album")){
              System.out.println(i.split("_")[0]);
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Paths`:

```
final String s = Paths.get("/mnt/sdcard/Album/album3_137213136.jpg")
    .getFileName().toString();
s.subString(0, s.indexOf('_'));
```

If you don't have Java 7, you have to resort to `File`:

```
final String s = new File("/mnt/sdcard/Album/album3_137213136.jpg").getName();         
s.subString(0, s.indexOf('_'));
```

Comment: Doesn't this assume that the file separator character is `'/'`?

Comment: Well yes, but it seems the OP is on Android; so it is quite a safe bet, I guess ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to match the substring

```
path.matches(".*album[0-9]+.*")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
 String path =    /mnt/sdcard/Album/album3_137213136.jpg
    path = path.subString(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1,path.indexOf("_"));
    System.out.println(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

## How to count substring in String in java

> At line no 8 we have to used for loop
> another optional case replace for loop using just while loop like as **while(true){. . .}**

```
public class SubString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count = 0 ;
    
    String string = "hidaya: swap the Ga of Gates with the hidaya: of Bill to make Bites."
            + " The hidaya: of Bill will then be swapped hidaya: with the Ga of Gates to make Gall."
            + " The new hidaya: printed out would be Gall Bites";
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) 
    {
        int found = string.indexOf("hidaya:", i);//System.out.println(found);
        if (found == -1) break;
        int start = found + 5;// start of actual name
        int end = string.indexOf(":", start);// System.out.println(end);
        String subString = string.substring(start, end); //System.out.println(subString);
        if(subString != null)
            count++;
        i = end + 1; //advance i to start the next iteration
    }
      System.out.println("In given String hidaya Occurred "+count+" time ");
      
    }

}
```